# Finding the cosine similarity of two sentences using LSA

Tags: python, gensim, cosine-similarity, lsa

I am trying to use Latent Semantic Indexing to produce the cosine similarity between two sentences based on the topics produced from a large corpus but I'm struggling to find any tutorials that do exactly what I'm looking for - the closest I've found is [Semantic Similarity between Phrases Using GenSim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31821821/semantic-similarity-between-phrases-using-gensim) but I'm not looking to find the most similar sentence to a query, I specifically want to use an LSI model to reduce the dimensionality of two sentences and then measure the cosine similarity of the two sentences. Please can someone help?

From the quoted article, I thought I might be looking at the below code and then having the cosine similarity calculation? But I'm stuck.

```
import gensim
from gensim import corpora, models, similarities
from gensim.models import LsiModel

# texts = list of list of words from a database
dictionary = corpora.Dictionary(texts)
corpus = [dictionary.doc2bow(text) for text in texts]
lsi = models.LsiModel(corpus, id2word=dictionary, num_topics=400)
doc_1 = "Mary and Samantha arrived at the bus station early but waited until noon for the bus"
doc_2 = "when the seagulls follow the trawler, it is because they think sardines will be dropped in the sea"
vec_bow_1 = dictionary.doc2bow(doc_1.lower().split())
vec_bow_2 = dictionary.doc2bow(doc_2.lower().split())
vec_lsi_1 = lsi[vec_bow_1]
vec_lsi_2 = lsi[vec_bow_2]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've succeeded in making `vec_lsi_1` a vector for your `doc1`, and `vec_lsi_2` a vector for your `doc2`, have you tried simply calculating the cosine-similarity between those two vectors? Cosine similarity is calculated by taking the dot-product of two vetors, then dividing that by their unit-norms. EG:

```py
import numpy as np

cossim = (
           np.dot(vec_lsi_1, vec_lsi_2) 
           /
           (np.linalg.norm(vec_lsi_1) * np.linalg.norm(vec_lsi_2))
         )
```

**Update for completeness:** If `vec_lsi_1` etc are sparse vectors – some form of list of `(index, value)` where unmentioned indexes are assumed to be `0.0` – then `np.dot()` may not work directly; see https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/matutils.html#gensim.matutils.sparse2full for a helper function to turn Gensim's sparse format into a dense numpy vector.

Comment: Duh, that is right. I think I was getting confused because vec_lsi_1 and _2 are lists of tuples, e.g. [(0, 2.5421721543245632), (1, 1.916669244322992), (2, -1.3872379805375552), (3, 0.3558633937347007), (4, -0.3629907789109514), (5, -0.08266164521723947), (6, -0.2437366769345134), (7, 0.8623269434308487), (8, 0.023915765119585236), (9, 0.5371951325481609)]. Obviously the first item in the tuple is an index, so I've just unpacked it and been able to do the cosine similarity. Silly me, thank you

Comment: Ah, yes. If the vectors display as a list-of-tuples, they're in a 'sparse' representation that might need either (a) conversion to a dense array (see for example https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/matutils.html#gensim.matutils.sparse2full); or (b) some alternate `dot` that works on sparse representations (see for example what can be done on Scipy's slightly-different version of compressed sparse vectors via https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.html). Glad you're on the right track!